# How to send a mail with global attachments?

Tags: c#

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Net.Mime;
    using System.Text;

    namespace AzureSendGridDemo
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("FromAddress", "Name");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("ToAddress", "Name"));
                msg.Subject = "Mail from Azure and SendGrid!";
                msg.Body = "This is just a simple test message!";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Attachments.Add("D:\image.jpg"); // if i put local path, it works.
                msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71nTxKhiqrL._UL1500_.jpg")); // if i put global path it doesn't works. It shows some errors are shown below:  
//Sendgrid credentials for sending mail using smtpclient wrapper class.
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587);
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
                client.Send(msg);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

If i am using global path, it shows errors are shown below in my console application:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
>              at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
>              at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>              at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>              at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType)
>              at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase..ctor(String fileName)
>              at System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName)
>              at AzureSendGridDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\SendGrid\AzureSendGridDemo\AzureSendGridDemo\Program.cs:line 41
>           Press any key to continue . . .

[image]

Comment: Please take a little more care with formatting before you post...

Comment: What is "global path"???

Comment: URLs are not acceptable filestream paths. You're going to have to make a webrequest for the image and put the resulting stream into the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you can not pass a URL to a e-mail like a attachment.

the URL is a link that you can put in the body of the message, or you can also use a WebClient class of C# to download the document and attach it to the e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload of the `Attachment` constructor that allows you to pass a url string. There is one though that accepts a `Stream` so you could do something like this...

```
var imageRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71nTxKhiqrL._UL1500_.jpg")
using (var imageStream = imageRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    var x = new Attachment(imageStream, "image/jpeg");
}
```